# Servlet Error - Checking Multiple Variables

Tags: java, servlets

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
 */
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Login() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        Connection conn = null;
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbName="Tamir";
        String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";



    try{  
         request.setAttribute("message", "");
        String nick = request.getParameter("check_name");
        String password = request.getParameter("check_password");


      Class.forName(driver).newInstance();  
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,"root", "tamir");
      //admin check
      /*
      java.sql.PreparedStatement st2 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname = ? or email = ? and password = ? and admin = T");
      st2.setString(1, nick);
      st2.setString(2, nick);
      st2.setString(3, password);
      ResultSet r2=st2.executeQuery();

      if(r2.next()) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("admin", nick);
    }
    */
      //regular check
      java.sql.PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname = ? or email = ? and password = ?");
      st.setString(1, nick);
      st.setString(2, nick);
      st.setString(3, password);
      ResultSet r1=st.executeQuery();

      if(r1.next()) {


            request.getSession().setAttribute("user", nick);
             request.getRequestDispatcher("/tf2main.jsp").forward(request, response);


      } else {



         request.setAttribute("message", "Username or password are incorrect.");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", null);  
         request.getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp").forward(request, response);

      }

    }catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    }

}
```

Hello. So I've made the code above and it is working perfectly, but when I add the comment [which I really need, in order to check if he's an admin... Cruical for me] it just throws the exception for some reason.

The only other souloution I've thought about was redricting to another servlet, doing the same action  somehow but that's impossible so I'm kinda stuck, you also can't use ERB.

I've tried everything and nothing works.

Edit: The error being throwed is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'T' in 'where clause'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2487)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
at Login.doPost(Login.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You should let the servlet framework handle roles.

Comment: Print out what the exception actually is with `ex.printStackTrace()`

Comment: @stdunbar https://pastebin.com/jZVx11iY this is what i've gotten. I really appriciate the help.

Comment: What type of column is `admin`?

Comment: Varchar (255), edited it, thanks @stdunbar

Answer (score 0):

Update the query to be something like:

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement st2 =
    conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname = ? or email = ? and password = ? and admin = 'T'");
```

Note the single quote marks around the `T` in the query.

Comment: It was infront of my eyes all along. Thanks!